# DbSet.Attach attempting to insert explicit value for generated identity column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have the following classes:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }
}
```

Then in a separate class I am running the following:

```
var entity = new MyEntity();

myContext.MyEntities.Attach(entity).State = EntityState.Added;

myContext.SaveChanges();
```

The call to SaveChanges throws the exception:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table MyEntity when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

At this point my schema is being created entirely by convention, and the Id column is supposed to be auto-generated. The problem seems to have something to do with my using `Attach` and setting `EntityState.Added` manually. When I instead use `Add` like so:

```
myContext.MyEntities.Add(entity);
```

It works just fine. However, I want to use `Attach` because in my real scenario `MyEntity` will have untracked child properties that already exist in the database. `Add` automatically sets the state of related untracked entities to `EntityState.Added`, and I don't want to have to manually set the state of those existing entities to `EntityState.Unchanged`.

What am I missing here? Why is EF attempting to insert an explicit identity value, even after attaching the entity and setting its state to `Added`?

Comment: It might be a EF Core implementation miss, but I would recommend not mixing the approaches. Either try `myContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;` or `myContext.ChangeTracker.TrackGraph(entity, node => node.Entry.State = !node.Entry.IsKeySet ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Unchanged);`

Comment: It is not "This is how you do" but look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43721383/how-is-the-difference-between-add-or-delete-an-entity-from-the-dbset-and-from-lo/43878589#43878589) for details. `myContext.MyEntities.Local.Add(entity)` may help you in not adding child properties.

Comment: @Smit Actually `Local.Add` seems to do exactly what I want. The related entities remain detached, but the added entity's ID references to them are correctly persisted in the DB on `SaveChanges`. Are you aware of any major caveats with simply using `Local.Add` for this type of scenario? I can see that because the related entities remain detached, they are not available in the DbContext after `SaveChanges`, but in my case that is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a by-design behavior in EF.
If you call Add(), it means that the object is not present on the database, so a key is generated for that entity.
If you call Attach(), it means that it is present in the db, so no key generation is performed, even if you set the state to added later.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know of any way to tell EF to generate an ID after Attach(), or __not__ mark related entites as Added on Add() ? The marking of related entities as Added is all I'm trying to avoid, so I don't have to set them to Unchanged manually.

Comment: @X-Malleus The only way I know is the one that you mentioned: setting the state to Unchanged or Detached. I know that there are a couple of third party libraries out there that solve this problem, but it was never that crucial of an issue for me.